# How to calculate the amount of blocks occupied by certain file sizes in a unix inode filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, inode

Given a hard disk with a Unix-like filesystem and the following specifications:

The block size is 4KB, the block address length is 4 bytes and the i-nodes have a traditional  structure (10 direct pointers, 1 indirect pointer, 1 double indirect pointer and 1 triple indirect pointer).

What is the number of blocks (including both the data and address blocks) occupied by the following files:

- File A with a size of 20 KBytes
- File B with a size of 200 KBytes
- File C with a size of 2000 KBytes
- File D with a size of 20000 KBytes

The problem here is that I can't even find the formula on how to solve this one. If I had the formula I would just substitute the values and be done. I don't ask you to solve it for me, I'm just asking for a guideline

Comment: Is this homework? it looks like you have just pasted the home work question, and made no effort. Show us what you have done so far, show us where you are stuck. We will help, but we are not going to do it for you.

Comment: Yes it is homework and I don't ask you to do it for me. There were more questions like "What is the maximum file size?" which I answered. The problem here is that I can't even find the formula on how to solve this one. If I had the formula I would just substitute the values and be done. I don't ask you to solve it for me, I'm just asking for a guideline @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: Did my answer or the link in the comment bellow it, give enough guidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be documentation somewhere on the data structure.

This is me working it through, I purposeful have not finished (it is your homework / learning).

For the 20K file it will be just the inode (no indirect blocks): so 20KB/(4KB/block) + inode = 5blocks + inode.

For the others you will need to know how many indirect pointers are in **an indirect block** (4KB / (4B/pointer) = 1K pointers). Sufficient for 4KB × 10 + 4KB × 1K = 4KB × ( 1K + 10 ) = 4KB × 1034 = 4136KB. (and don't forget the inode. I don't know how big it is).

For double and triple indirect. You will have a tree:
1K of pointers (one block) pointing to 1K of pointers (1 block) each, but each pointer can be null, so not all of these blocks are allocated.

Then for triple this is just extended.

Also note that you first allocate the direct blocks, and subtract this from the size. Then allocate indirect and subtract, then allocate double indirect and subtract, then allocate triple indirect. If it dose not fit, then you need to upgrade to a more modern file-system (you will have already done this, but the older one is used for teaching, as it is easier to get the basics).

Comment: [This lecture webpage](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring09/V22.0202-002/lectures/lecture-24.html) has a picture that might help in understanding the structure.